# Objective c - variable to label

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, variables

Is a little problem with save int variable to label.

```
int i = idpole;
[lid2 setText:@"%i", i];
```

Thats bad, but i tried more thing... i cant set this "settext:i", because this doesnt work. I try found something on google, but without sense.

Comment: Helo, when you get the answer of your question, try to accept it so that everyone will know that you got ur answer. To accept an answer click on the White Tick before the reply.

Answer (score 7):

use

```
int i = idpole;
[lid2 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
```

Answer (score 3):

The `text` property of label is a `NSString`, so you can not set an integer directly. You need to convert that int to a string. You can use any of the followings:

```
lid2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", idpole]; // no need of temporary i
// or
[lid2 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", idpole]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = idpole;
[lid2 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
```